# Drupal 7 taxonomy term views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I created two vocabularies taxonomy: products and gallery. Created two different views of these terms. Includes standard representation "Taxonomy term" and now on the product page of the node are displayed in a gallery - no! What could it be?

Comment: Why don't you enable the default taxonomy/term view?

Comment: So I use the default taxonomy term views! On one page, the content is displayed, and the other reason is not.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the Taxonomy Views Integrator module (https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi) provided me with great flexibility and control. Basically it allows selective overriding of taxonomy terms and/or vocabulary with the view of your choice.

Here's a [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/577646) on how to implement it.

Hope it helps.